# Python array (getting the syntax order right)

Tags: python, arrays

If you run this code, then both outputs are the same: `['A','B',' ',' ']`.
Don't know what I am doing wrong but shouldn't the output of `array2` be blank: `[' ',' ',' ',' ']` and `array1` should be: `['A','B',' ',' ']`?

```
reset = [" "," "," "," "]

array1 = []
array2 = []

array1.append([" "," "," "," "])
array2 = array1

array1[0][0] = "A"
array1[0][1] = "B"

print (array1)
print (array2)
```

Comment: You're setting `array2 = array1`, so they both point to the exact same list and will therefore be the same. Did you mean to do `array2 = reset`?

Comment: `array2 = array1` **does not** create a copy of your array. It simply instructs both variables to point to the same object (i.e. array).